# jqPlot - How to show text on y axis?

Tags: jqplot

I have an array that contains dates for x-axis and integer values between 1-3 for my y- axis like this:

```
chartData = [["19-Jan-2012",1],["20-Jan-2012",2],["21-Jan-2012",1],["22-Jan-2012",3]];
```

**Problem 1:**
I want to see text instead of 1 and 2 and 3, like this:
 "High" instead of 3 ,
  "Medium" instead of 2,
 "Low" instead of 1.

How it can be done ?

**Problem 2:**

How to show labels next to each point permanently and not only on mouse over with highlighter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third parameter like this `[[1,4,'mid'], [3 5,'hi'], [7,2,'low']]` and use this in your options string

```
series:[{
  pointLabels:{
    labels:['mid', 'hi', 'low'],
    location:'se',
    ypadding: 12
  }
}]
```

Try this also I think this what you exactly want http://www.jqplot.com/tests/point-labels.php
But Still you have to pass a numeric value to the data with x series.

In the above link you can find the exact solution I guess..

Cheers..

Comment: You do not need `labels:...` since you specify their values in the data you give. Therefore, the following is enough  `pointLabels:{ show:true, location:'s', ypadding:3 }` As taken from the examples you liked to.

Comment: I added the pointLabels as you said and as shown on jqPlot site, but I still don't see the legend next to the point. Do I miss some reference?

Comment: mmm.It should work now..did you forget to add null for other points that you do not want like this. [[-12, 7, null], [-3, 14, null], [2, -1, '(low)'],
      [7, -1, '(low)'], [11, 11, null], [13, -1, '(low)']];. Or if you want all the points to be marked, as Boro says you can add point labes {show:true} in the option string.